# tbb parallel_for: Object with intrusive list node can be part of only one intrusive list simultaneously

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, tbb, intrusive-containers

I'm currently porting a program that was originally written on Windows 10 to a redhat system (`VERSION_ID="8.8"`) that has `g++` version `8.50. 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)`.  I installed `tbb` with `vcpkg`.  I've reduced my problem to the following minimal working example.  (Note, the original project has over a hundred files.  I've tried to keep some things from the `CMakeLists.txt` that may be related, but I'm unsure):

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -mtune=native -march=native -g")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros -fno-trapping-math-freciprocal-math -fno-rounding-math -fno-signaling-nans -fexcess-precision=fast")
endif()

project(Example LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(example
    example.cpp
)

find_package(TBB CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(example
    TBB::tbb
    TBB::tbbmalloc
)
```

`vcpkg.json`:

```
{
    "name": "vt",
    "version-string": "",
    "dependencies": [
        "tbb"
    ],
    "builtin-baseline": "36fb23307e10cc6ffcec566c46c4bb3f567c82c6"
}
```

`example.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>

#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint32_t> vec(100);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
        vec[i] = i;
    }

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, vec.size()),
        [&](tbb::blocked_range<size_t> r)
        {
            for (size_t i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i)
            {
                vec[i] = vec[i]+1;
            }
        });

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine on my windows machine (using Visual Studio).  It also compiles on the red hat machine, however it will only run in `Debug` mode.  When compiled in `Release` mode, I get the following error:

```
Assertion node(val).my_prev_node == &node(val) && node(val).my_next_node == &node(val) failed (located in the push_front function, line in file: 135)
Detailed description: Object with intrusive list node can be part of only one intrusive list simultaneously
Aborted (core dumped)
```

To build in release mode I run the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

(For `Debug` I simply add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to the `cmake` configuration call)

---

Some things I've tried (that did not work):

- remove the `builtin-baseline` from the `vcpkg.json`
- remove all of the options set for `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`
- remove `set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMZATION TRUE)`
- remove `set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)`

I've also tried doing this exact small problem on my personal Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS machine (with `g++` version `11.3.0`), and I got the exact same results.  It compiles but only works when built as `Debug` but not `Release`, giving the same error as above.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if ThreadSanitizer doesn't work with TBB because I get a data race report from ThreadSanitizer when running your example - even if I empty the body of the lambda.

Comment: I tried `tbb::parallel_for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](uint32_t& value) { ++value; });` too with the same result. Odd. Can you use C++17 and execution policies instead or would that require too much work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah I'd really need to stick with TBB for right now.

Comment: I guess you'd say that given the amount of files involved. It's strange because the execution policies in gcc uses TBB under the hood, so `std::for_each(std::execution::par, ...` should be very similar to `tbb::parallel_for_each(...` - but one works for me, the other don't :-) Edit: Now, that was a lie. ThreadSanitizer says the same thing when using execution policies. Hmm....

Comment: It complies (but not links) [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wej75obW1).

Comment: @MarekR It does on trunk though

Comment: @ChrisGnam The output you get comes from an assertion from within `intrusive_list.h` which I don't even have in my TBB 3.16 installation. I'm assuming you have TBB 4.x?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using version 2021.5.0 of oneTBB as provided by vcpkg

Comment: @ChrisGnam Ok, one has to seach inside the vcpkg release to find out what version they packaged, but I am guessing it's 4.x since 3.x is old. Fwiw, I think your program looks perfecly fine so there's probably "something else" going on.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine discovered that adding the following line to the `CMakeLists.txt` is a work around for now, and he believes he's identified what the underlying problem actually is:

`add_compile_definitions(TBB_USE_ASSERT)`

Here is a brief summary of what he said.  I've added it to an issue I submitted on the `vcpkg` repository.  Hopefully it helps resolve the issue, but if not, hopefully this work-around helps anyone else who stumbles across this same issue.  (NOTE: It likely has a performance penalty over a true solution on the vcpkg side of things)

#### EDIT: Description from my colleague:

> Its fundamentally a build system issue. I had to spend some time single stepping through the allocator. Basically, it was asserting that uninitialized memory happened to contain its own address. I had to get a side-by-side setup with a working and broken copy to track where that value got set in the working copy.
>
> The code that sets it is in the class constructor for the intrusive_list_node helper class and was conditional on a preprocessor macro. That preprocessor macro checks if runtime debugging assertions are enabled. If assertions are enabled, it does some extra initialization. If not, it skips that because it would be replaced as soon as the node is used. The only time tbb would ever traverse a newly created list is when sanity checking it on the first insertion.
>
> The actual issue is that vcpkg is building the tbb binary with assertions enabled. When you do a debug build, you also build things with tbb assertions enabled. That tiny one line of initialization code actually ends up getting compiled when building your application, not tbb. This is because it has to do with initializing data you set aside in your program.
>
> So when you built it in release mode, debug assertions were disabled in your code and it skipped the extra initialization. But you then get combined with a version of tbb that was built with runtime assertions enabled. It tries to assert that the internal data structures are intact and that fails because it was left in an uninitialized state that would actually have never been used by anything other than the sanity check.
>
> TLDR: The issue is vcpkg is combining you release mode program with a version of tbb with debugging assertions still enabled. That CMake directive says to compile your code assuming debugging assertions in tbb are enabled.

Comment: here https://godbolt.org/z/EEP8q4MnY there is no such macro definition in compiler options. So this is property of your setup.

Comment: If I understand the answer correctly, it's actually an issue in the vcpkg package, so the solution could possibly be to modify how the tbb libraries are being built - and file an issue with the vcpkg package maintainer :-)